# Confusion about the proof of fence theorem for strong fences

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the [book](http://dlx.b-ok.org/genesis/1127000/b3bbba7fc0acd330143c328c6b446b8e/_as/[John_H._Hubbard,_Beverly_H._West_(auth.)]_Differe(b-ok.org).pdf) of *Differential equations: A dynamical system approach* by Hubbard and West, at page 27, it is given that:

> A strong fence for the diff. equations $x' = f(t,x)$ is nonporous.

And in the first line of the proof, it says that

> The hypothesis $\alpha(t_0) \leq u(t_0)$ means that ...

,where $\alpha(t)$ is a lower fence for the given diff. equation.

However, a fence is related with the slope of the function x, i.e $x'$, not with the actual value of x. In other words, $\alpha'(t) \leq x'(t)$ for all t in I, where I is some interval, so we can not conclude that $\alpha(t_0) \leq u(t_0)$.

So, what am I missing ?

**Edit:**

A link to the book is added, so for more detail, you can check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the misunderstanding of the definition of nonporous fence.

> The definition says that If there exist a $t_0 \in I$ such that
>   $\alpha (t_0) \leq u(t_0)$ for a given solution of the diff. equation,
>   then $\alpha (t) \leq u(t)$ for all $t > t_0$ in I.

Therefore, let first assume that $\alpha(t)$ is a strong fence for the ODE, and let $u(t)$ be a solution to the ODE.If $t_0$ exists, we have either;

$\alpha(t_0)  = u(t_0)$, or

$\alpha (t_0) < u(t_0)$. (If t_0 is not exists, we have nothing to prove.)

In the former case, we have

$$\alpha(t_0) < f(t_0, \alpha(t_0) = f(t_0, u(t_0)) = u(t_0),$$ 
right after $t_0$, $\alpha(t) < u(t)$, and since by definition 
$\alpha'(t) < u'(t)$ for all t in I, we have 
$$\alpha(t) < u(t)\quad \forall t > t_0.$$

In the latter case, as similar argument follows.